# Error when fading the contentview in xamarinforms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

good afternoon,

I want this ContenPage to last 3 seconds and then fade out.

This is the XAML code:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     BackgroundColor="White">
            
            <Image Source="log.png"
                   HeightRequest="250"
                   x:Name="logo"/>
            
            <Label Text="FROM"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>

            <Label Text="MundoD"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

I'm using the FadeTo method to achieve this requirement, but the screen does not fade, this is the C# code

```
            logo.Opacity = 0;
            await logo.FadeTo(1, 2000);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new IntroOne();
```

[Result, The view does not fade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnJu8.jpg)

I would appreciate some help <3

Comment: where is this code being called from?  Why don't you set the initial opacity value in the XAML?

Comment: The view is called PresentationView, and the code is called from Presentation.xaml.cs,
If the opacity value is 1, the logo does not appear.

Comment: do you want the logo to fade OUT?  Then you need to use `FadeTo(0, 2000)`

Comment: I want the page to disappear and take me to another page.

Comment: if you want to go from 100% opacity to 0% opacity, then use `FadeTo(0, 2000)`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "logo.Opacity = 0"
and change "await logo.FadeTo(1, 2000)" to "await logo.FadeTo(0, 2000)" as Jason said above.
Also, you may want to override the OnAppearing() method to set the logo's Opacity. Otherwise,
the logo will not display next time you back this page.
code is like:

```
protected override  OnAppearing()
{
base. OnAppearing(); 
pic.Opacity=100;
}
```